# How to repeat in every page custom code using pdfkit

Tags: python, wkhtmltopdf, pdfkit

With fastapi, I created this endpoint

```py
@app.post("/html_pdf")
def html_pdf(html: str = Form(), css: str = Form(""), orientation: str = Form("")):
    rutaTMP = "/tmp/"
    suffix = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%y%m%d_%H%M%S")
    path_to_wkhtmltopdf = r'/usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf'
    rute_and_filename = "{}{}-{}.pdf".format(rutaTMP,
                                             str(uuid.uuid4()), suffix)
    cssRute = "{}css{}-{}.css".format(rutaTMP, str(uuid.uuid4()), suffix)
    config = pdfkit.configuration(wkhtmltopdf=path_to_wkhtmltopdf)

    f = open(cssRute, "a")
    f.write(css)
    f.close()
    options = {'encoding': 'UTF-8'}
    if orientation:
        options['orientation'] = orientation
    pdfkit.from_string(html,
                       output_path=rute_and_filename,
                       configuration=config,
                       css=cssRute,
                       options=options)
    try:
        with open(rute_and_filename, "rb") as pdf_file:
            encoded_string = str(base64.b64encode(pdf_file.read()))
            encoded_string = encoded_string.split("'")[1]
            remove(cssRute)
            remove(rute_and_filename)
        return encoded_string
    except:
        return None
```

It receives the html, the css and the orientation, then returns the encoded string for a PDF file. The html contain the definition of a table. Now I need to repeat the header of the table in every page. Also, I need to add only to the first page, another custom html (who contain another table with some extra info). The document must look as follows:
First page:

- Information
- Header of the table with the names of columns
- The table

Next pages:

- Header of the table with the names of columns
- The rest of the table

I tried passing the **cover** option to **from_string**, but I got only errors.